# join из двух таблиц в один стобец

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеются три таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE #main (date_time date, id varchar(50)); -- основная таблица
INSERT INTO #main VALUES
('2020-07-01',  '11'),
('2021-02-09',  '11'),
('2019-01-29',  '22'),
('2018-03-14',  '22'),
('2020-04-19',  '22');

 
CREATE TABLE #t1 (date_time date, id varchar(50), product varchar(50)); -- данные до 2020
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES
('2019-01-29',  '22',   'Phone'),
('2018-03-14',    '22',    'Charger');
 

 CREATE TABLE #t2 (date_time date, id varchar(50), product varchar(50)); -- данные после 2020
INSERT INTO #t2 VALUES
('2020-07-01',  '11',   'PC'),
('2021-02-09',  '11',   'Printer'),
('2020-04-19',  '22',   'Phone');
```

В таблицах *t1* и *t2* присутствуют даные для таблицы *main*.
В *t1*- данные до 2020 года, *t2*-после.
Вопрос, как к таблице *main* приджойнить стобец *product* , который будет в себя включать данные как из *t1*, так и *t2*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

объедините выборку обеих таблиц через `union all`

```
select *
from #main
inner join (
    select x from #t1
    union all
    select x from #t2 
 ) ON (...)
```

либо

```
select * from #main
inner join #t1 ...
UNION ALL
select * from #main
inner join #t2
```

либо джойнте обе, и выберите непустое

```
select m.*, COALESCE(t1.product, t2.product)
from #main as m
left join #t1 as t1 on (..) 
left join #t2 as t2 on (..)
```

тут также можно использовать и `ISNULL(t1.product, t2.product)`

Answer (score 4):

Что бы исключить пересечение id, которые могут находится и в t1 и в t2, попробуйте разделить их по году, пример:

```
select 
    m.date_time,
    m.id,
    case when #t1.id is null then #t2.id else #t1.id end,
    case when #t1.product is null then #t2.product else #t1.product end,
    case when #t1.date_time is null then #t2.date_time else #t1.date_time end
from #main m
   left join #t1 
        on m.id = #t1.id
        and YEAR(m.date_time) < 2020
   left join #t2 
        on m.id = #t2.id 
        and YEAR(m.date_time) >= 2020
```

Соединение с первой таблицей по id и году меньше 2020
Соединение со второй таблицей по id и году равному или выше 2020

---